# How prepare .ipa for AWS Device Farm

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ipa

I am trying to test an app (as .ipa file) that i got through iTunes AppStore in AWS Device Farm. I get "Could not start UIA agent, error code -6" error at the start of the test run. Should .ipa file be prepared a special way for AWS Device Farm (other than to have iOSDevice target that, I believe, all App Store apps have)? Thanks.

Automation Output from ADF run:

1471897919.415000   1536    20  Version: 1.2 - Build: Jul 12 2016 17:06:58
1471897919.416000   1536    10  Command Mode: 0, Execution Mode: 1, Help: 0, Debug: 0, Version: 0, Performance: 1, Debugger: 0, Timeout: 60, UIA Message Timeout: 60, iOS Major Version: 8, Args Count: 0, Env Count: 6, Test Args Count: 0, Test Env Count: 1, UDID: 8f1af0db41435d8247d91f4032e3761b1332fac5, UIA Script Path: /tmp/scratchNE4m06.scratch/appium-bootstrap-b8a200215802a847.js, Application Bundle ID: com.abc.def, XCTest UI Bundle ID: (null), Output Directory: /tmp/scratchNE4m06.scratch/automation21G8lT
1471897919.416000   1536    10  Registering process signal handlers
1471897919.416000   1536    10  Connecting to device (8f1af0db41435d8247d91f4032e3761b1332fac5)
1471897919.454000   1536    10  Connecting to lockdownd (ideviceautomation)
1471897919.961000   1536    10  Starting lockdownd service (com.apple.instruments.remoteserver)
1471897920.012000   1536    10  Connecting to instruments service (instruments)
1471897920.076000   1536    10  Connecting to installation proxy service (ideviceautomation)
1471897920.843000   1536    10  Requesting instruments service (com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol)
1471897920.844000   1536    10  Requesting instruments service (com.apple.instruments.UIAutomation)
1471897920.945000   1536    10  Requesting instruments service (com.apple.instruments.server.services.activity)
1471897920.971000   1536    10  Requesting instruments service (com.apple.instruments.server.services.graphics.coreanimation)
1471897921.072000   1536    10  Installation proxy get install path for bundle com.abc.def
1471897921.136000   1536    10  Installation proxy get container path for bundle com.abc.def
1471897921.174000   1536    10  Installation Path: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A6C6B4C6-D8E3-4534-9EDF-4FEE32385A49/ChatTouch.app/ChatTouch, Container Path: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/535ED47C-C324-4FE7-AE19-DC004DFB3C06, Secondary Installation Path: (null), Secondary Container Path: (null)
1471897921.281000   1536    20  Launching process for bundle com.abc.def
1471897921.281000   1536    10  Processcontrol launching suspended process
1471897921.589000   1536    10  Processcontrol launched process with pid 0
1471897921.589000   1536    10  Waiting for bundle com.abc.def process to enter state running within 10 seconds
1471897921.695000   1536    10  Bundle com.abc.def process entered state running
1471897921.695000   1536    10  Processcontrol observing pid 201
1471897921.795000   1536    10  Processcontrol resuming pid 201
1471897921.896000   1536    10  Configuring activitymonitor launch environment of pid 201
1471897921.998000   1536    10  Starting activitymonitor sampling for pid 201
1471897922.099000   1536    20  Started activitymonitor sampling for pid 201
1471897922.099000   1536    10  Starting coreanimation sampling for pid 201
1471897922.201000   1536    20  Started coreanimation sampling for pid 201
1471897922.201000   1536    20  Starting execution mode: UIAutomation
1471897922.201000   1536    20  Starting agent for com.abc.def with PID: 201
1471897932.032000   1536    40  Could not start UIA agent, error code -6
1471897932.032000   1536    40  Failed to run execution mode 1
1471897932.032000   1536    10  Stopping activitymonitor sampling for pid 201
1471897933.016000   1536    20  Stopped activitymonitor sampling for pid 201
1471897933.016000   1536    10  Stopping coreanimation sampling for pid 201
1471897934.017000   1536    10  Cleaning up coreanimation service
1471897934.121000   1536    20  Stopped coreanimation sampling for pid 201
1471897934.121000   1536    20  Stopping bundle com.abc.def (201)
1471897934.121000   1536    10  Processcontrol stop observing pid 201
1471897934.222000   1536    10  Processcontrol kill pid 201
1471897934.324000   1536    10  Waiting for bundle com.abc.def process to enter state stopped within 10 seconds
1471897934.425000   1536    10  Bundle com.abc.def process entered state stopped
1471897934.425000   1536    10  Releasing instruments service (com.apple.instruments.server.services.processcontrol)
1471897934.425000   1536    10  Releasing instruments service (com.apple.instruments.UIAutomation)
1471897934.527000   1536    10  Releasing instruments service (com.apple.instruments.server.services.activity)
1471897934.527000   1536    10  Releasing instruments service (com.apple.instruments.server.services.graphics.coreanimation)
1471897935.552000   1536    10  Could not receive bytes from service, error code -1
1471897935.552000   1536    10  Stopping instruments message receiver

Comment: Are you trying to run fuzz tests or a particular test framework against the app?

Comment: I am trying to run appium tests in python against this app (one that I took from iTunes App Store)

Comment: Can you share the run URL for your run ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, This is a secure AWS account, so I am not sure how I can provide URL without account credentials. I added Automation Output logs from the run to the original message. This test was working fine with a version of this app taken from GooglePlay. I am just not sure - is iTune App Store app even testable with appium on iOS in ADF or it should be rebuild in some special way. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies. I should have provided context. I work for the device farm team and will be able to access the work logs. Alternatively you can also post on the AWS forums under Device Farm and we can pick it up from there too.

Comment: Great. If there is an option to contact you privately it would be more convenient. The run URL suffix is projects/50d315a8-318b-412e-ba3d-ed4651974c68/runs/4bec3dfb-7e04-4e1e-a9e8-079f97edd213

Comment: Please post on AWS Device farm forums and I should able to pick this up from there.